# Is there any way of integrating NLua in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lua

Recently I was interested in making Lua support inside of Unity. For that you have the bindings NLua and KeraLua. My problem is that I tried adding the dll files to `Assets\Plugins` manually. This solution didn't work, so I tried importing both source codes to unity and importing Lua bindings inside of `Assets\Plugins`. This didn't work either and I'm out of ideas. any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks for everyone helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MoonSharp** is a Lua interpreter written in C#. I'd suggest that you use this for your Unity project, because it is easier to sandbox with & implement.

https://www.moonsharp.org/